# Stenciljs CSS global variables

Tags: css, css-variables, stenciljs, stencil-component

I am unable to get global css variables working as described in the ionic stencil [docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling/).

I created a 'variables.css' file in 'src/global/', then put "globalStyle: 'src/global/variables.css'" into the "stencil.config.ts" file.

I then created a set of css variables in the variables.css and attempted to use them in my component's css file; however, the defaults are used since it fails to load the global variables.

```
// stencil.config.ts
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
    namespace: 'mycomponent',
    outputTargets:[
        {
            type: 'dist'
        },
        {
            type: 'www',
            serviceWorker: null
        }
    ],
    globalStyle: 'src/global/variables.css'
}


// src/global/variables.css
:root {
    --qa-primary-color: #2169e7;
    --qa-secondary-color: #fcd92b;
    --qa-dark-color: #0000;
    --qa-light-color: #ffff;
    --qa-font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    --qa-font-size: 12px;
}


// src/components/my-component.css
.main {
    background: var(--qa-dark-color, yellow);
}
.first {
    color: var(--qa-primary-color, pink);
}
.last {
    color: var(--qa-secondary-color, green);
}
```

Feel free to take a look at the test [repo](https://github.com/mriess260/test-component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented the functionality myself using the [copy config](https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#copy) to copy my global/variables.css from the src/ directory to www/ and dist/. Additionally, for testing I add a stylesheet link tag for global/variables.css in the index.html file. There is no need to set the globalStyle config if you follow this process.

While this doesn't address the fact that the process described in the [docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling) seems to be incorrect, it does provide the desired effect.

```
// stencil.config.ts
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'mycomponent',
  outputTargets:[
    {
      type: 'dist'
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null
    }
  ],
  copy: [
    { src: 'global' }
  ]
}

// html.index
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global/variables.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This actually worked for me. But can't we embed the "global/variables.css" into the build file?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using SASS then you can add this in your stencil.config.ts file

```
...   
plugins: [
    sass({
      injectGlobalPaths: ["src/global/variables.scss"]
    })
  ]
...
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/{YOUR_NAMESPACE}.css">` to `src/index.html`.

Comment: This worked for me and it seems to be the right way of doing it since all artifacts for  components are in the /build directory

Comment: this is not working after publishing the package and using in angular.. any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to the shadow DOM while using @component decorator we have a property shadow make it false. This should be followed across nested components. Refer
https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling#shadow-dom

```
@Component({
  tag: 'to-do-card-list',
  styleUrl: 'to-do-card-list.css',
  shadow: false,
})
```

[Refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je6G7.png)

Comment: This is not really the case. If it were, my solution would not have worked. Note when this question was asked, and the state of StencilJS at that time (specifically in regards to shadow dom).